# Dao and Service of a complex object

Tags: spring, service, dao

So i have this complex object, for example:

```
@Entity
public class House {

private Kitchen kitchen;
private LivingRoom livingRoom;
private MainBedRoom mainBedRoom;
private Toilet toilet;
etc...


}
```

now each object (Kitchen,LivingRoom etc..) in the House class is extremely complex with non primitive fields and what not..

I have the following services:

```
@Service
public HouseService {


}

@Service
public KitchenService{


}
```

.. and so on..

What my question is:

If i create a new House object within my HouseService, Do i have to use the other services for that creation method?

It seems that i don't even need all the other services at all since House is the root of all the objects and all i need is one (apparently big) HouseService? is that right?

i.e. :

```
HouseService.createNewHouse {

House house  = new House(...);
Kitchen kitchen = new Kitchen(...);
... 

   house.setKitchen(kitchen);
  this.dao.save(house);
  return house; 
  }

}
```

Comment: What do these services do?

Comment: Basic service stuff (some crud basically and other things)

Answer (score 1):

Although you could, don't make your life complicated. I assume you have multiple DAOs for your each of your Entity classes. Just `@Inject` (or `@Autowired) and use them directly in each`Service` class.

Your `@Service` classes should already by `@Transactional` so you gain nothing (unless there is specific business logic) from going through other `@Service` classes.

Instead of

```
@Service
public class FirstService {
    @Autowired
    private SecondService secondService;
    @Autowired
    private FirstDao firstDao;

    @Transactional
    public void saveFirst(First first) {
        secondService.saveSecond(first.getSecond());
        firstDao.save(first);
    }
}

@Service
public class SecondService {
    @Autowired
    private SecondDao secondDao ;

    @Transactional
    public void saveSecond(Second second) {
        secondDao .save(second);
    }
}
```

Just go for the DAO directly

```
@Service
public class FirstService {
    @Autowired
    private SecondDao secondDao;
    @Autowired
    private FirstDao firstDao;

    @Transactional
    public void saveFirst(First first) {
        secondDao.save(first.getSecond());
        firstDao.save(first);
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly should i use the services in conjunction to one another??